# storing the variable value while run from cron

Tags: cron

sh

## !/bin/sh

export count=$(sqlplus -s 'username/passwd@xyz'<

When I run this script manual , script runs fine.
When I keep it in crontab entry as follows

27 16 * * * /www/abc/a4.sh >a4.log

The a4.log doesnot have any data echoed.

Please let us know how to hold the value returned to a variable via sql query

Comment: tried all the options but no luck can you suggest any other way

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting

```
&>> your_file.log
```

behind a line in

```
crontab -e
```

Try using

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &>> your_file.log
```

…
at the beginning of a BASH script.
Also use >> which appends to the file rather than overwriting to it.